# How to understand memory usage on Windows and Linux?

Tags: java, linux, memory

I have a Java application which needs to run several hours to process some data. I run it on both a Windows machine and a Ubuntu machine. On the Linux machine, throughout the duration, the System Monitor shows that the memory usage has been in the range of 5.5G to 7.5G, mostly around 6G. On my Windows machine, the range has been 8G - over 11G.

Why is there such a big difference? One factor is the OS. and the other one may be due to different size of RAM. My Linux machine has 64G, while my Windows has 16G.

Comment: Might be the jvm. What version of java are you running on windows and linux?

Comment: Any other applications running on windows machine the time your application is processing data such as antivirus etc.,?

Comment: memory usage of the JVM process or the overall system ? It it is the second one, it is helpless.

Comment: There are a lot of configuration aspects that could come into play here. To me this reads like you are calling your garage saying "my car makes strange noises. How do I fix that?"

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis, Java 1.8

Comment: No much stuff running on Windows. One thing I noticed was that the memory usage goes steadily to nearly 95%, then come down to 60%; and then recycle, same pattern. I am afraid there might be OutOfMemory problem, but no.